Cannot run dlv for go debug with administrator privileges in vscode
My configuration in launch.json is as follows:
{
    "name": "Launch as Root",
    "type": "go",
    "request": "launch",
    "mode": "debug",
    "program": "${fileDirname}",
    "env": {},
    "args": [],
    "console": "internalConsole",
    "asRoot": true,
},

But when I click on the debug button in vscode, it runs /home/1033/go/bin/dlv dap --listen=127.0.0.1:45505 --log-dest=3 from /home/1033/Dev/kite/mypackage in the debug console. Since /home/1033/go/bin/dlv is not a root dlv, I encounter permission problems when debugging my program, I have no problem if I use the root user's dlv (/bin/dlv) for debugging in the terminal. So I want to know how can I run the dlv program under root (/bin/dlv) in the debug console when I click the debug button in VS Ccode.
I've tried configuring the go.alternateTools parameter and giving /home/1033/go/bin/dlv administrator privileges, and both failed, but opening vscode with root privileges can successfully use the root user's dlv (/bin/dlv), but I don't want to use this option due to the flashing. program.
